# Why `v:lnum` doesn't return 1 for the first line?

Tags: vimscript, indentation

I really want to know why doesn't Vim's `v:lnum` return 1 for very first line. I tried googling and searching in Vim's docs, but I can't find an answer.

I understand that `v:lnum` returns *line number*, but I don't understand which line `v:lnum` is referring to..? A little aside; from `help v:lnum` I understand that you can only use `v:lnum` with some expressions including `indentexpr` (the one I'm interested in the most for my indentation script).

**workflow test 1**

1. make a `.vim` file. e.g `check.vim`
2. append `echo v:lnum`
3. open new vim window and `:source check.vim`
4. append some text to the file and `:source check.vim` again
5. no matter how many lines I add to the file I always get `0` back

I think I understand this, since Vim docs say that `v:lnum` only works in conjunction with some specific expressions then you would expect `0` when I'm trying to use `v:lnum` by itself.

**workflow test 2**

1. make `check.vim` file
2. append

   ```
   setlocal indentexpr=Check()
   function! Check()
     let line = getline(v:lnum)
     echo v:lnum line
   endfunction
   ```
3. open new vim window and `:source check.vim`
4. append some text to the file and `:call Check()` function
5. I DON'T get *first line* no matter what I do.. I can get any other lines.. e.g

   - if I only type in one line into the file and `:call Check()` I get `0` and `''`
   - if I type in second line into the file and `:call Check()` I get `2` and `check line two` back
   - if I keep adding lines to the file and run `:call Check()` on lets say the fifths line I get `5` and `check line five`

I think I understand that `v:lnum` returns index of the last line typed into the file. But why doesn't it return the index of the very first line type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`v:lnum` is a Vim internal variable, that is only **valid** while evaluating the `indentexpr`, `foldexpr`, `formatexpr` options. In other contexts this does nothing.

This means, that in you indentexpr or formatexpr you can find out, what line is currently being evaluated and react accordingly.

For indentexpr this means, it will get filled, once you start indenting your file, e.g. using `gg=G`, for formatexpr this will be evaluated when defining your foldmethod and folding is enabled and formatexpr will be evaluated using the gq command.

In other context, this is really invalid. It should actually be always 0 so there might be a (minor) bug there.

Comment: great thanks for the answer. I get all what you are saying. Its pretty much straight from the docs. However I don't think I even need to indent to get `v:lnum` value. I get it without indenting ! The question is why I can't get `v:lnum` equals to one..? it is either `0` or `>= 2`..? And I'm not sure what you mean by "minor bug"..?

Comment: You are setting the indentexpr for the buffer and when inserting new lines, Vim will internally call the indentexpr to determine the indent and init v:lnum to each line number, leaving v:lnum with the last line number of your buffer.

Comment: so why can't I get `v:lnum` equal to `1` once I typed in one line..? When I do that `v:lnum` equals to `0`. If I type second line `v:lnum` equals to `2` Where is `1` ..?

Comment: Because it depends on the number of lines your buffer has. So it will be 1, if you have a buffer with a single line and call the indentexpr function (e.g. using "V=" in a buffer with a single line)

Comment: sorry, can you spell it out for me. I don't get it how to call the indentexpr function.. I thought `:call Check()` is calling `indentexpr` since `:set indentexpr?` equals to `indentexpr=Check()`... What is this `V=` thing.. ?
Once I typed single line in I `:buffers` and here is output `:buffers                                                                                                               
  1 %a + "[No Name]"                    line 1` and `call Check()` is `0`

Comment: Just because you set the indentexpr() does not mean it will be magically used when calling the function. It will be used, whenever you want to indent a line, e.g. using '=' read the help at `:h =`